# .htaccess permanent redirect - browser strangely adds GET variable to URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to implement a very basic redirect for specific pages with htaccess, however the browser adds a GET variable to the new URL after the redirect:

```
Redirect 301 /branding/ABCDE http://example.com/branding/NEW
```

New URL in browser:

```
http://example.com/branding/NEW?slug=ABCDE
```

How can I correct this so that the ?slug=ABCDE does not show up?

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue...

Comment: No, cleared cache multiple times, still same behavior on different browsers

Comment: Some other redirection rule you are not aware of then.

Comment: The rule you posted will _not_ create such a parameter.

Comment: Can you post your full .htaccess in question

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your `.htaccess` file, the best guess is that you have a conflict with other (specifically mod_rewrite) directives in your `.htaccess` file. There is nothing actually wrong with the `Redirect` directive itself that you posted.

The `Redirect` directive is a mod_alias directive and executes *after* mod_rewrite, despite the apparent order of these directives in your `.htaccess` file. A URL of the form `/branding/ABCDE` most probably requires rewriting (using mod_rewrite) for it to be useful by your application. This rewrite occurs before the `Redirect`, but any query string will be maintained.

It is not recommended to mix both `Redirect` and `RewriteRule` directives in the same config file, because of these unexpected conflicts.

Change your redirect to use mod_rewrite instead and make sure this is near the top of your config file. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^branding/ABCDE$ /branding/NEW [QSD,R=301,L]
```

You will need to ensure your browser cache is cleared before testing, since the erroneous 301 (permanent) redirect will likely have been cached by your browser. To avoid caching issues, it is advisable to first test with 302 (temporary) redirects.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4+) will discard any query string that might be present on the initial request.